# What was the effect of the Disannexation Act of 1784?

Tags: 18th-century, scotland

I am trying to find more specific information on the effect of the Disannexation Act of 1784 which provided means for those whose property had been confiscated after the ‘45 to regain it after paying debts. I am curious for specific examples of Scotsmen who were able to get their estates back, which estates were eligible, and for how long they were able to take advantage of the act (for instance, if someone affected had left to fight for the Crown and returned years after the act’s passing, could they still take advantage of it?)

Comment: There are, presently, 4 close flags because of "too wide a subject area". I disagree with those because the question is about how a specific Act could have been utilized by the people -- we don't need Question 1) Which estates were eligible under Act?, and 2) Who could have used the Act? because a good answer to that describes the scope of the Act should answer both questions in any case. 
What I do think is missing, however, is some background research describing what you have found and where you have looked.

Answer (score 1):

[The Exchequer Records at the National Records of Scotland](https://www.nrscotland.gov.uk/research/guides/exchequer-records) include an archive of papers about forfeited estates for the years 1716-1824. You might be able to find relevant secondary sources that draw from these records, but so far I'm not having much luck finding anything that directly addresses your question. And unfortunately the records do not appear to have been digitized, so you would need to go in person to access them yourself if you are so inclined.